# How do you count records for the current month?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using mongo or mongoose, how would I get the total number of records for the current month?

I have this but it is giving me a total for every month, I just want a count of records for the current month.

```
  const genTotal = await General.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          year: { $year: "$visitDate" },
          month: { $month: "$visitDate" },
        },
        Total: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

I also tried this:

```
  const genTotal = await General.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          month: { $month: "$visitDate" },
        },
        Total: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
    {
      $match: { $month: 3 },
    },
  ]);
```

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a match stage in the beginning to filter out the past month's documents try this:

```js
let month = new Date().getMonth();

const genTotal = await General.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: [{ $month: "$visitDate" }, month]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                year: { $year: "$visitDate" },
                month: { $month: "$visitDate" },
            },
            Total: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: This is looking promising, thanks! But for some weird reason it is showing the month as February or rather "2" ?

Comment: Because in JavaScript months start from 0. So 2 is March. So months range between 0-11 in JavaScript.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I see. A bit confusing but okay

Comment: One last thing, is there a way to extract the month name out of the query as "2" isn't very helpful, especially if it doesn't represent February

Comment: No choice but to put switch case or something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870419/how-to-convert-number-to-month-in-mongo-aggregation/49870988